# Equivalent functions to find one and the only element that occurs odd times in given array of integers

Tags: ruby

I have a simple question for ruby.

The following method returns an element  that occurs odd times in given array of integers. It is guaranteed that there exists one and the only element that occurs odd times.

```
seq.detect { |n| seq.count(n).odd? }
```

Yet another succint solution is this:

```
seq.reduce(:^)
```

I need explanation of the latter approach.

Comment: For the second solution, I guess you have a premise: all other elements occurs even times, there is only one occurs odd times. Is that right?

Comment: @sam Right, it was one of the solution in codewar problems. There was indeed a premise which is exactly same as what you said. I just forgot it. Respect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, ^ is xor method.

`1 ^ 1 = 0, 
 1 ^ 1 ^ 1 = 0 ^ 1 = 1, 
 1 ^ 2 = binary(01) ^ binary(10) = binary(11) = 3`

So, by using reduce, you traverse the array, and apply the xor operation.

So, the xor result of elements which occurs even times is 0, and the xor result of elements which occurs odd times is the element itself.

So, the overall xor result is the element which occurs odd times.

For example, you have `arr = [2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 7, 5]`

When you call `arr.reduce(:^)`, it works similar as the following:

```
((((((2 ^ 3) ^ 3) ^ 5) ^ 2) ^ 7) ^ 5)
```

Then xor satisfies commutative law and associative law, So, the it's equivalent to the following

```
(2 ^ 2) ^ (3 ^ 3) ^ (5 ^ 5) ^ 7 = 0 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ 7 = 7
```

So, you find the answer is `7`

Comment: Good answer but your explanation is not correct when you say "...and do the xor operation to every two adjacent elements." It has nothing to do with adjacency. The point is that if one value of `n` is xor'd into `reduce`'s memo and `n` is xor-ed again the memo will be the same as it would have been had neither of the two `n`'s been xor'd. This means that if `n` is xor'd an even number of times the memo will be the same as it would have been had no `n`'s been xor'd.

Comment: Yes, the sentence you pointed out is not correct. It's the memo xor with the next element until the end. Thank you.

Comment: Therefore,  xor-ing all elements appearing an even number of times have no effect on `reduce`'s memo. That leaves the one element that appears an odd number of times. If it appears `m` times `m-1` appearances have no effect on `reduces`'s memo, mean that the memo must equals the element that appears an odd number of times.

Answer (score 1):

Your premise is incorrect.  They give different results:

```
seq = [1,2,3,2]
seq.detect { |n| seq.count(n).odd? }  # => 1
seq.reduce :^  # => 2
```

You can see that the answers are different and that the latter's answer isn't even correct by the filtering criteria.

I think the intent was to use the facts that `^` (XOR) is transitive, that `x^x == 0` for all `x`, and that `x^0 == x` for all `x`.  Consequently, all values occurring an even number of times should cancel themselves out.  The problem is when the XOR of two or more of the other values yields one of the values in the list, i.e., `1^3 == 2`.

---

The additional constraint fixes the problem I outlined above.  If one and only one value occurs an odd number of times, then it can't be XORed with another odd occurrence to produce a collision. All the even occurrences are self-cancelling, leaving only the one odd occurrence XORed with zero, i.e., the odd occurrence.

Comment: Thanks. How can I fix the latter approach? I mean using reduce?

Comment: I just updated my question. I overlooked an important condition